# Label with :before misaligned and overflowing in Chrome

Tags: html, forms, css, google-chrome

I run into some problems with the following CSS that customizes the display of radio buttons ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/chalarangelo/pen/mBYyMx)):

```css
/* Styling for form and fieldset - skip over this */

form {
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #c9c9c9;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 0.5rem 1.125rem;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0.0625rem solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
  margin: 0.125rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}


/* Styling for labels and input groups */

label {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

.input-group {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Hiding <input type="radio"> elements */

[type="radio"] {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(100%);
  clip-path: inset(100%);
}


/* Actual styling for the radio buttons */

.input-group [type="radio"]+label {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Creates the little circle on the side */

.input-group [type="radio"]+label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.375rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  content: '';
  border: 0.0625rem solid #bdbdbd;
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #212121;
  margin-left: -1.25rem;
}


/* Focus and hover styling to highlight the circle */

.input-group [type="radio"]+label:hover:before,
.input-group [type="radio"]+label:focus:before {
  border-color: #0288d1;
}


/* Focus styling in case the input itself is focused, not the label */

.input-group [type="radio"]:focus+label:before {
  border-color: #0288d1;
}


/* Border radius for the circle */

.input-group [type="radio"]+label:before,
.input-group [type="radio"]+label:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* Styling for checked radio buttons */

.input-group [type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #212121;
  content: '';
  margin-left: -1.25rem;
  bottom: 0.625rem;
  left: 0.25rem;
  width: 0.625rem;
  height: 0.625rem;
}
```

```html
<form style="width: 350px">
  <fieldset>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</p>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="radio" id="rad1" tabindex="0" name="radio-group-1">
      <label for="rad1">Duis erat eros, sagittis vitae risus varius</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="radio" id="rad2" tabindex="0" name="radio-group-1">
      <label for="rad2">Sed volutpat efficitur dolor, id suscipit leo ultrices at</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

While the styling I have created works perfectly fine in Firefox, it seems to have a couple of problems in Chrome, as you can see in the pictures below:

[image]

Firefox displays the label and custom radio button as expected, properly aligned and without any text overflowing its parent container. Chrome, on the other hand, misaligns the circular box for the radio button, as well as some of the label's text overflows its parent container. Why is that and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` for Label and in this selector `.input-group [type="radio"]+label:before` replace the `bottom` property with `top`:

```css
/* Styling for form and fieldset - skip over this */

form {
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #c9c9c9;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 0.5rem 1.125rem;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0.0625rem solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
  margin: 0.125rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}


/* Styling for labels and input groups */

label {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

.input-group {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Hiding <input type="radio"> elements */

[type="radio"] {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(100%);
  clip-path: inset(100%);
}


/* Actual styling for the radio buttons */

.input-group [type="radio"]+label {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Creates the little circle on the side */

.input-group [type="radio"]+label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.375rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  content: '';
  border: 0.0625rem solid #bdbdbd;
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #212121;
  margin-left: -1.25rem;
}


/* Focus and hover styling to highlight the circle */

.input-group [type="radio"]+label:hover:before,
.input-group [type="radio"]+label:focus:before {
  border-color: #0288d1;
}


/* Focus styling in case the input itself is focused, not the label */

.input-group [type="radio"]:focus+label:before {
  border-color: #0288d1;
}


/* Border radius for the circle */

.input-group [type="radio"]+label:before,
.input-group [type="radio"]+label:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* Styling for checked radio buttons */

.input-group [type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  position: absolute;
  background: #212121;
  content: '';
  margin-left: -1.25rem;
  top: 0.625rem;
  left: 0.25rem;
  width: 0.625rem;
  height: 0.625rem;
}
```

```html
<form style="width: 350px">
  <fieldset>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</p>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="radio" id="rad1" tabindex="0" name="radio-group-1">
      <label for="rad1">Duis erat eros, sagittis vitae risus varius</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="radio" id="rad2" tabindex="0" name="radio-group-1">
      <label for="rad2">Sed volutpat efficitur dolor, id suscipit leo ultrices at</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```